# Using SIFT with OpenCV3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, opencv3.1, debian-based

Ok, just got my first Raspberry pi (3). Went on to install Opencv 3.1.0 using Adrian's guide:

[How to Install Opencv 3 on Raspbian Jessie](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/)

Installed OpenCV WITH CONTRIB packages as I knew I would need them.

So OpenCV is working fine now. The issue is when I try to use SIFT:

"'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'"

I did and still do everything by the book, including working on 'cv' environment etc.

I tried checking the site-packages dir of both the python dir and the 'cv' env dir and couldn't find any mention of 'contrib' or 'xfeatures2d'.
Maybe that's the problem? How can I check that the contrib packages were actually compiled with OpenCV?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you use cv2 package?

Comment: @Miki Yes, I use the 'cv2' module. 'cv' is the python environment in which opencv is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Because u installed the latest version in OpenCV where they removed sift and surf, I am not sure how they substitute them, anyway u have to install older version of opencv 3.4.2.16 also make sure that opencv contrib of the same version is installed, thats the last working version working with sift/surf not sure if there are special versions for raspberry pi